# curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo curl: (60) server certificate verification failed

Tags: git, ssl, curl, repo

I tried to install repo in my ubuntu, but experienced following failure:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > /bin/repo
```

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

I googled all the solution about "curl: (60) server certificate verification failed.", but they all don't work on my side. who knows about this?

Comment: Is the `ca-certificates` package installed on your system?

Comment: no, so far,  I am using '-k' option to workaround this issue.

Comment: So...you already have a work around, and the solution is to install `ca-certificates`.  Do you need anything else?